# Entity Framework Core add unique constraint code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I can't find way to add a unique constraint to my field with using attribute:

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    // [Index("IX_FirstAndSecond", 2, IsUnique = true)] not supported by core
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using these packages:

```
 "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
 "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
 "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.1",
 "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
```

Comment: Samples of fluent  Api for indexes see at https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasindex-method

Answer (score 566, accepted):

On EF core you cannot create Indexes using data annotations.But you can do it using the Fluent API.

Like this inside your `{Db}Context.cs`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<User>()
        .HasIndex(u => u.Email)
        .IsUnique();
}
```

...or if you're using the overload with the buildAction:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<User>(entity => {
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.Email).IsUnique();
    });
}
```

You can read more about it here : [**Indexes**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help,
it's the right solution!

Comment: In case someone lands here looking for a solution that works when using MS Identity schema, I suggest setting the unique constraint on the NormalizedEmail field, not Email (of the AspNetUsers entity).  Using different case might fail to violate the constraint even if it's the same email address, depending on collation setting of the db.

Comment: This code is not working for column of type string :(
Is there any way to add unique constraint on string column ?

Comment: Go for `HasAlternateKey`

Comment: Did you see the official example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes It is for the `string` @JoharZaman

Comment: I tried this when I was working on this but now i don't need to implement this. Btw Thank you for your comment. @Sampath

Comment: As Chamika suggests too, this is another option.  It depends on the RDBMS that you target too. From what I can see :  Sometimes  a unique-constraint automatically creates an index (ms-sql-server?), sometimes not (postgres?).   Bubuilder.HasAlternateKey(o => new { o.PropertyOne, o.PropertyTwo, o.PropertyThree });

Comment: Upvote for right answer but this seems like a lot of faff having to write a giant `OnModelCreating` for all your classes. I wish it could be implied from DataAnnotations!

Comment: what if we create a new migration this entity will not implement then and i have to reassign it as unique ?

Comment: @gurkan Please post your own answer. I think that will help the community.

Comment: This is outdated by now. Using `[Index(nameof(<key column>), IsUnique = true)]` it is possible to define indices on the entity class.

Comment: Is there any option to Set an Error msg while trying to insert a duplicate value?

Answer (score 155):

Also if you want to create Unique constrains on multiple columns you can simply do this (following @Sampath's [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes))

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasIndex(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName })
            .IsUnique(true);
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 101):

Since Entity Framework Core (EF Core) 5.0 we can [configure Unique Indexes via Data Annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations#index-uniqueness).

It is little different to e.g. EF6, because we cannot set it on the property itself but instead on the class.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;           // for [Index] attribute
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;   // for [Key] and [Required] attributes

namespace FunWithDataAnnotations
{
    [Index(nameof(EmailAddress), IsUnique = true)]
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For further information on Indexes and Data Annotations see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: The `Index` attribute is on namespace `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and requires the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` nuget package. I had the models and DbContext on separate projects, and was having a hard time finding it thinking it was on `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` (it's not).

Answer (score 26):

Ef core support unique configuration.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
  builder.Entity<Account>()
    .HasIndex(account => account.Email)
      .IsUnique();
}
```

Ef core support multiple unique keys

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
      .HasKey(account => new { account.Id, account.Email, account.RoleId });
}
```

Don't forget run ef core command to make migration and update the database

```
>> dotnet ef migrations add MigrationName -c YourDbContextName
>> dotnet ef database update -c YourDbContextName
```

Answer (score 20):

Solution for EF Core

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Passport { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public ApplicationContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=efbasicsappdb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasAlternateKey(u => u.Passport);
        //or: modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasAlternateKey(u => new { u.Passport, u.Name})
    }
}
```

DB table will look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Passport] NVARCHAR (450) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [AK_Users_Passport] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Passport] ASC)
);
```

[Ref to EF Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys)

Comment: According to EF Core docs : `If you just want to enforce uniqueness of a column then you want a unique index rather than an alternate key. In EF, alternate keys provide greater functionality than unique indexes because they can be used as the target of a foreign key.`

Comment: Reference to bigworld12's comment : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#alternate-keys

Comment: This is what I had to use to get EF Core to generate a unique constraint (rather than a unique index) to match my existing database.

Answer (score 12):

To use it in EF core via model configuration

```
public class ApplicationCompanyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Company> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Company"); 
        builder.HasIndex(p => p.Name).IsUnique();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The OP is asking about whether it is possible to add an Attribute to an Entity class for a Unique Key.  The short answer is that it IS possible, but not an out-of-the-box feature from the EF Core Team.
If you'd like to use an Attribute to add Unique Keys to your Entity Framework Core entity classes, you can do what I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51421616/3936440)

```
public class Company
{
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [UniqueKey(groupId: "1", order: 0)]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [UniqueKey(groupId: "1", order: 1)]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string CompanyLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [UniqueKey] attribute is a defined attribute by Microsoft? or one should define it himself?

Comment: [UniqueKey] attribute is a custom Attribute that I've developed to enable addition of unique keys within the .cs entity classes (and not through the DbContext's OnModelCreating() method)

Comment: That's great. Could you please put the code of the custom attribute you developed?!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49526370/is-there-a-data-annotation-for-unique-constraint-in-ef-core-code-first

Answer (score 4):

For someone who is trying all these solution but not working try this one, it worked for me

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{

    builder.Entity<User>().Property(t => t.Email).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_EmailIndex") { IsUnique = true }));

}
```

Comment: Not working in EFCore 6. `HasColumnAnnotation` should be changed to `HasAnnotation`, but I don't know what are correct names for new `IndexAnnotation` and `IndexAttribute`

Answer (score 2):

None of these methods worked for me in .NET Core 2.2 but I was able to adapt some code I had for defining a different primary key to work for this purpose.

In the instance below I want to ensure the OutletRef field is unique:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Outlet>()
                .HasIndex(o => new { o.OutletRef });
        }
    }
```

This adds the required unique index in the database.
What it doesn't do though is provide the ability to specify a custom error message.

Answer (score 0):

We can add Unique key index by using fluent api. Below code worked for me

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(p => p.Email).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_EmailIndex") { IsUnique = true }));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @Kuldeep Singh's answer:

When using older versions of .net his answer worked.
When you want to create a unique index on multiple columns:

```
Property(p => p.Prop1).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Unique", 1) { IsUnique = true }));
Property(p => p.Prop2).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Unique", 2) { IsUnique = true }));
```

Note: the name 'IX_Unique' has to be the same for both columns. And The order specified in the IndexAttribute constructor is crucial for multi-column indexes, as it determines the column order in the index.