# Is there a data annotation for unique constraint in EF Core (code first)?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I am wondering if there is a data annotation for unique constraint in Entity Framework Core 2 code first approach?

Comment: Let us know you want it on issue [#10864](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10864).

Comment: @bricelam, thanks, i did.

Comment: Strange that they removed this functionality when it was already part of EF6. It's annoying that you can do _almost_ everything through data annotation attributes but there are still things you have to fall back to the fluent API for.

Comment: There are more things that can only be done by fluent API because fluent API is far more flexible and expressive than annotations. When multiple entities and/or properties are involved in one mapping construct annotations are nothing but spaghetti programming.

Comment: If it is an option to upgrade your .NET Core version, here is the solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations#index-uniqueness

Comment: @Daan not for myself but for others i think it could be very helpful if you add it as an answer with quick sample pasted

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In *EF Core* you could use the extension method **`HasAlternateKey`** in fluent API only. There are **no data annotations** to realize a **unique constraint**.

This MS doc article - [Alternate Keys (Unique Constraints)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/unique-constraints) - will explain how to use and which further possibilities are exist.

A short example from link above:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
            .HasAlternateKey(c => c.LicensePlate)
            .HasName("AlternateKey_LicensePlate");
    }
}

class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string LicensePlate { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

Also it's possible to define an **unique index**. Therefore, in **EF Core** you can use the fluent API's extension method `HasIndex` or the data annotation way with the attribute `[Index]`.

In this MS doc article - [Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes) - you will find further information how to use.

Here an example for an unique index with **fluent API**:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .HasIndex(b => b.Url)
            .IsUnique();
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Here the same example, but with **data annotation**:

```
[Index(nameof(Url), IsUnique = true)]
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

---

*Update 2021-09-10*

- added additional info how to use with data annotation, because it's now available in EF Core;

*Update 2021-09-24*

- fixed missing IsUnique property in attribute example

Comment: .HasIndex and IsUnique are not working with a column of type nvarchar(string).

Comment: As far as I know you could use NVARCHAR or VARCHAR if it has a length less than 900 Byte. You could define it for a column with the fluent API or attributes. The example code above is directly from linked MS Doc article. If you set a max length from e.g. 32 for a GUID instead of [N]VARCHAR(MAX) it should work. Maybe this answer helps you too stackoverflow.com/a/27687748

Answer (score 22):

To update, there is now a code-first annotation.

```cs
[Index(nameof(MyProperty), IsUnique = true)] // using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
public class MyClass
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255), Required]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's funny no one suggest this in other answers

Comment: Until .NET 5 the EF Core [Index] attribute did not exist: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations#index-uniqueness

Answer (score 11):

I've written an Attribute class that can allow you to decorate your EF Core Entity class properties to cause a Unique Key to be generated (without the Fluent API).

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

/// <summary>
/// Used on an EntityFramework Entity class to mark a property to be used as a Unique Key
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class UniqueKeyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Marker attribute for unique key
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="groupId">Optional, used to group multiple entity properties together into a combined Unique Key</param>
    /// <param name="order">Optional, used to order the entity properties that are part of a combined Unique Key</param>
    public UniqueKeyAttribute(string groupId = null, int order = 0)
    {
        GroupId = groupId;
        Order = order;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // we simply return success as no actual data validation is needed because this class implements a "marker attribute" for "create a unique index"
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

In your DbContext.cs file, inside OnModelCreating(modelBuilder) method, add this:

```
// Iterate through all EF Entity types
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    #region Convert UniqueKeyAttribute on Entities to UniqueKey in DB
    var properties = entityType.GetProperties();
    if ((properties != null) && (properties.Any()))
    {
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var uniqueKeys = GetUniqueKeyAttributes(entityType, property);
            if (uniqueKeys != null)
            {
                foreach (var uniqueKey in uniqueKeys.Where(x => x.Order == 0))
                {
                    // Single column Unique Key
                    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uniqueKey.GroupId))
                    {
                        entityType.AddIndex(property).IsUnique = true;
                    }
                    // Multiple column Unique Key
                    else
                    {
                        var mutableProperties = new List<IMutableProperty>();
                        properties.ToList().ForEach(x =>
                        {
                            var uks = GetUniqueKeyAttributes(entityType, x);
                            if (uks != null)
                            {
                                foreach (var uk in uks)
                                {
                                    if ((uk != null) && (uk.GroupId == uniqueKey.GroupId))
                                    {
                                        mutableProperties.Add(x);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        entityType.AddIndex(mutableProperties).IsUnique = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion Convert UniqueKeyAttribute on Entities to UniqueKey in DB
}
```

Also in your DbContext.cs class, add this private method:

```
private static IEnumerable<UniqueKeyAttribute> GetUniqueKeyAttributes(IMutableEntityType entityType, IMutableProperty property)
{
    if (entityType == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entityType));
    }
    else if (entityType.ClrType == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entityType.ClrType));
    }
    else if (property == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(property));
    }
    else if (property.Name == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(property.Name));
    }
    var propInfo = entityType.ClrType.GetProperty(
        property.Name,
        BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        BindingFlags.Public |
        BindingFlags.Static |
        BindingFlags.Instance |
        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
    if (propInfo == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return propInfo.GetCustomAttributes<UniqueKeyAttribute>();
}
```

Usage in your Entity.cs class:

```
public class Company
{
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [UniqueKey(groupId: "1", order: 0)]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

You can even use this across multiple properties to form a Unique Key across multiple columns in your table.  (Note the use of "groupId" and then the "order")

```
public class Company
{
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [UniqueKey(groupId: "1", order: 0)]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [UniqueKey(groupId: "1", order: 1)]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string CompanyLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There are multiple issues with this answer. If `Order` is anything but `0` the UniqueKey attribute is skipped. Also, it throws an exception when creating composite unique keys as it tries to create duplicate indexes (one for each member of the composite index). Although it has shown me how to get my code working so there's that I guess...

Comment: If you are using a single property UniqueKey (or multiple property UniqueKey) you must use a zero-based Order value -- for each property being decorated with UniqueKeyAttribute.
If you aren't using the Order properly, then I could imagine where you are getting the exception being thrown.  Use the zero-based Order properly, and show a bit more restraint on negativity.

Comment: Did you mean OnModelCreating and not OnModelGenerating?

Comment: @D.Kermott Documentation states that calls like IsUnique() need to be called in OnModelCreating() hence Justin meant OnModelCreating for sure.

Comment: FYI IsValid() override added

Comment: How do I cater for Name, I have an existing database with keys, I do not want to run migrations again.

Answer (score -2):

In the `DbContext.cs` file, inside `OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)` method, on the last `ForEach`, I had `.OrderBy(o => o.Order)`

Comment: I don't want to downvote, you better delete this answer. Has nothing to do with the question

Comment: Thank you for your attention but I think it is important to have the multiple key in the right order, don't you? Otherwise, what is the point of having this property (except for the 0)?

Comment: what does it have to do with the question ?

Comment: I can not add comment to the use of Attribute, so I added it here, it is in relation with the question isn't it?