# How to make unique key two ways in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a table

```
class Sample {
  public string From;
  public string To;
}
```

I want to make sure that the From and Two are unique throughout

Meaning if From = 2, and To = 1. There cannot be a combination of 1,2 or 2,1 in the Table

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the database add a check constraint that From < To.

And in addition to preventing (1,2),(2,1) this design gives you a simple method to find a pair, as you know it will be stored as (1,2) and not (2,1).

Comment: know that my Keys are String, so assume my From = 'Apple',To = 'Banana'

Comment: Your solution helped Thanks

Comment: Let's imagine there are no records in your table. If you receive From='Banana', To='Apple', what is the expected behaviour of your application? With the description you set on your question my understanding was, you should insert it, if next time you get From='Apple', To='Banana', you won't let it insert.

However, if you use this constraint, it only lets From='Apple' and To='Banana'.

Answer (score 0):

It is not straightforward, but what you can do, create a third column which is a concatenation of those two columns, and use that third column as a unique key.

How you should generate this third column so that it to be the same for both (From,To)=(1,2) and (2,1)? Assuming that the third column name is **Both** you can use basic algorithm given below.

```
class Sample {
  public string From;
  public string To;
  public string Both;
}
```

**Algorithm:**

```
if(From.ComareTo(To) >= 0) {
   Both = To + From;
} else {
   Both = From + To;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the model definitions, in your context you need to add

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Sample>()
    .HasIndex(u => new { u.From, u.To })
        .IsUnique();
```

Then, the index will be added.

Check [Entity Framework Core add unique constraint code-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41246614/entity-framework-core-add-unique-constraint-code-first/41257827)

Is very similiar but for one filed only.

**Edit**

If you need the pair unique, then combine it with the other answer, add a field in your table with the combination ordered,

```
class Sample {
  public string From;
  public string To;
  public string Both;
}
```

Then set the value of both ordered:

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    sample.From, sample.To
}
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .ToList();
sample.Both = string.Join(":", list);
}
```

This way the unique constraint is against the combination of both, in order, so, does not matter what they put in `from` and in `to`

Comment: Wrong answer! It does not preserve the pair uniqueness.