# Unique constraint on property that is not the primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'd like to set another property of a class as unique when using entity framework.
I checked out other pages with similar questions but the answer doesn't work as I expected.

[Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41246614/entity-framework-core-add-unique-constraint-code-first/41257827)

Now I have an simple object where the ID is the key but I also want the name to be unique as well. It shouldn't be a combined primary key.

```
public class Building
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

 public DbSet<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
    public BandContext(DbContextOptions<BuildingContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Building>(entity => {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Name).IsUnique();
        });
    }
```

I'd like the outcome to be like this:

```
ID    Name
1     White house    OK
2     Green house    OK
3     White house    Unique constraint violation
1     Louvre         Unique constraint violation
```

I think i'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: @progman you are right, that was a copy mistake to Stackoverflow. Made an edit to the post.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: How exactly do you know it is not working? What exactly is not working? What is the table structure in your database? Have you run a migration to update the database schema?

Comment: @ErikEJ I can still add double names without any warning or exception. I would expect an unique constraint violation when adding additional buildings with the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add migration after this change and run `Update-Database` in package manager console to apply these changes